# I don't know how to make the Text type in Unity to work with the text properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the score(scoreText) to be updated as the position of my player Game Object increases, but it just seems like there is no text property in type text even though they're supposed to be one?
There is this error: error CS1061: 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no accessible extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
'''

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Text : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        this.scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString();
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that your *class* is called `Text`, too and your class does not have a Property `text`. The compiler does not know that you actually want your `scoreText` field to be of type `UnityEngine.UI.Text`.

You can either rename your class (maybe to something like `Score`) or you can clarify that you want `scoreText` to be a `UnityEngine.UI.Text`:

```cs
public class Score : MonoBehaviour // rename class
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreText; // or clarify namespace
}
```